# Why it is Centroid?

Tags: geometry

Three circles with radii 1 unit touch each other externally while a bigger circle encloses all 3. A smaller circle is drawn in the area enclosed by the 3 circles,concentric with bigger circle such that it touches all the 3 circles. The ratio of the radius of smallest circle to that of the biggest circle is

[image]

Comment: Actually in Answer , they have taken the centre as centroid and then they find circumradii and inradius , but my doubt is why centre is centriod

Comment: For an equilateral triangle centroid is the same as center of symmetry.